# Rotate a CircleImageView around another CircleImageView's pivot point

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.android

I am working at a project in Xamarin. Android where I use the `CircleImageView` NuGet package(which is just a library for `RoundedImageViews`). I have a `CircleImageView` (call it `civ1`), and another one(call it `civ2`). I want to `rotate` `civ2` around `civ1`'s center, at a certain angle. I know I can use

`android:rotation="90"` to rotate `civ2`, but this will just rotate it around its own center which I don't want. So how could I `rotate` `civ2` around `civ1`'s center point?

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/IDEQSVFL"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcornerslayout">
        <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/civ1"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ME_RotatoryKnobMainImage" />
        <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/civ2"
            android:layout_width="11dp"
            android:layout_height="11dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ME_RotatoryKnobLed" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This is my code.

[image: check this picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android:rotation="90" to rotate civ2, but this will just rotate it around its own center which I don't want. So how could I rotate civ2 around civ1's center point?

If you want the small circle to be in certain position that related to the circle 2, you just need to modify  `layout_marginLeft` and `layout_marginTop` to change the position of the small circle:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/IDEQSVFL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/snow">
    <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/civ1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/timg2" />
    <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/civ2"
        android:layout_width="11dp"
        android:layout_height="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:src="@drawable/timg2" />
</FrameLayout>
```